# modulation wheel affects last knob turned in ableton live

Tags: ableton-live, modulation

Problem:
Some software synthesizers should respond to the modwheel but instead ableton live changes the value of the last knob I've turned in a software synthesizer.

Background:
I use the small modulation wheel on the akai mpk mini mk2 (which may be relevant or not). Also if I assign CC1 (which is modulation?) to a knob on the midi controller ableton live acts as described in the problem. It should be some kind of setting in ableton live but I can't find it anywhere in the options or on the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CC1 should be the Mod-wheel signal sent by default by your controller if it complies to the midi standards.
Nothing prevents you from changing that and also as you have apparently already done, assign this note to another controller.

What might have happened is that by routing your mod-wheel to a particular controller it cancelled the link of the signal CC1 to your others synths.

Are you selecting you synth's track and opening your synth to see if you mod - wheel (the one on your plugin) responds?

You could also try to go on your midi configuration panel (in [Live's preferences](https://www.ableton.com/en/help/article/lives-midi-ports-explained/)) to activate the **track** button if it is not done yet.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for the information. Turned out that I had to learn two things. First: Midi map mode maps cc numbers global in the project which means if I map cc1 I can't use it for anything else anymore.
Second: I have to look at the small hand icon. If I put an instrument in an instrument rack and select the instrument itself it works fine. If I select the instrument rack cc 1 to cc 8 controls the 8 knobs.

Thanks for the help. Helped me thinking in the right direction :)

Comment: Your welcome :)